# EF6 code first 1 foreign key to multiple tables, error updating database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a review table that may have records linked to different tables. For instance, the 1st record could be linked to my Submission table, the 2nd row could be linked to my Project table. I would like to know the best way to define that relationship.

Here is a sample of my RequestReview table:

```
[Table("RequestReview")]
public class RequestReview : BaseEntity
{
    [Key,  DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid RequestReviewId { get; set; }

    public Guid ResourceToReviewId { get; set; } // Foreign key of other tables
    [ForeignKey("ResourceToReviewId")]
    public virtual ProjectSubmission ProjectSubmissionToReview { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ResourceToReviewId")]
    public virtual Project ProjectToReview { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Here are a couple of the other tables:

```
[Table("ProjectSubmission")]
public partial class ProjectSubmission : BaseEntity
{    
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ProjectSubmissionId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ProjectSubmissionToReview")]
    public virtual ICollection<RequestReview> RequestedReviews { get; set; }
    //...
}

[Table("Project")]
public partial class Project: BaseEntity
{    
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ProjectToReview")]
    public virtual ICollection<RequestReview> RequestedReviews { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

I can Add-Migration, but when I try to Update-Database I get this:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.RequestReview_dbo.Project_ResourceToReviewId". The conflict occurred in database "Mkp", table "dbo.Project", column 'ProjectId'.

My Migration looks like this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddForeignKey("dbo.RequestReview", "ResourceToReviewId", "dbo.Project", "ProjectId");
    }
```

***UPDATE:***

I was also trying this, but it did not work:

```
[Table("RequestReview")]
public class RequestReview : BaseEntity
{
    [Key,  DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid RequestReviewId { get; set; }

    public Guid ResourceToReviewId { get; set; } // Foreign key of other tables
    [ForeignKey("ResourceToReviewId")]
    public virtual Resource ResourceToReview { get; set; }
    //...
}

[Table("ProjectSubmission")]
public partial class ProjectSubmission : BaseEntity
{    
    [Key, ForeignKey("Resource"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ProjectSubmissionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ResourceToReview")]
    public virtual ICollection<RequestReview> RequestedReviews { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

I cannot create the migration. I get this message trying to create the migration:

> The entity type 'PublicationSystem.Model.Project' on which the navigation property 'RequestedReviews' is declared is not a base type for the type 'PublicationSystem.Model.Resource' referred to by the inverse navigation property 'ResourceToReview'.

Comment: quote "Would that work?" why don't you just try it . quote "Or is there a better way?" More info, I don't understand, just looks like a one to many, where is the one to many tables aspect come in?

Comment: Look for *polymorphic associations*.